# setValues of 1 column from a 2d array in Google Sheets script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to set the values of 1 column on a sheet to those stored in a specific column of a 2d array. I thought this would work but it gives an error...

```
sheet.getRange(sheetStartRow, sheetColumn, sheetEndRow-sheetStartRow+1, 1).setValues(myArray[][myArrayColumn]);
```

Comment: `myArray[][myArrayColumn]` is not proper javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below...

`sheet.getRange(sheetStartRow, sheetColumn, sheetEndRow-sheetStartRow+1, 1).setValues(myArray.map(function(v,i){return[v[myArrayColumn]]}));`

Am not sure of your myArray, so make due adjustments... but the below worked for me...

```
  var arr=s.getRange("A:B").getValues()
  var bvals= arr.map(function(v,i){return [v[1]]})
  s.getRange("C:C").setValues(bvals)
```

Comment: Exactly what  I needed!

Comment: Right on! Thank you!